# Laravel optional argument for routing

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I have written the following router. But I like to have the `{id}` and `{name}` to be optional, and in case the user does not add them URL, nor error be popped up.

In other words, now when I visit this URL:

```
http://localhost/public/mostafa/23/testName
```

it works,

But when I visit the following URL it errors (404):

```
 http://localhost/public/mostafa
```

I want the above URL to work and not to throw 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "?" to provide for optional parameters.

```
Route::get('/blah/{part1?}/{part2?}',function($part1=null, $part2=null) {
    //...
});
```